# Function not defined error although it is

Tags: python, python-3.x

About 3 days ago I started learning Python as a hobby.
Today I wanted to try to program a text adventure in Python.

When I tried to test the code I had an error, but I don't know why. Can someone please help me?

The code:

```
name = 'bot'
def intro():
    print("On day you wake up but you don't remember anything, except your name.\n"
          "You are in a unknown room. Right in front of you is a unlocked Computer.\n"
          "\nWhat do you do?\n"       
          "\n1) Go to the computer.\n"
          "2) Try to escape.\n"
          "3) ")

    anwser = input(">>> ")

    if anwser.lower() == "1" or "go to the computer":
        return computer()
    elif anwser.lower() == "2" or "try to escape":
        return escape()

intro()

def computer():
    print("You go to the computer and there is a folder called" +name)
    print("\nWhat do you do:\n"
          ""
          "\n1) Open the folder.\n"
          "2) Delete the folder\n"
          "3) Lock the computer and try to escape.")
    anwser = input(">>> ")

    if anwser.lower() == "1" or "open the folder":
        print("You open the folder an there a lot of dokuments.\n But you see a folder called \" Project Raspbrain \"")
    elif anwser.lower() == "2" or "delete the folder":
        print("You decide to delete the folder but you feel wired and fall on the ground.\n"
              "You die!")
    elif anwser.lower() == "3" or "lock the computer and try to escape":
        escape()

def escape():
    print("You see a door on your right side, you decide to go through it but there are two guards in front of you\n"
          "What do you do?\n"
          "\n1) Kill the guards"
          "\n 2) Run")
    anwser = input(">>>")

    if anwser == "Kill the guards" or "1":
        print("You try to kill the guards but don't have any weapons.\n Instead they kill you.\n You die")
    elif anwser == "2" or "run":
        print("You try to run but you stumble an fall on your head.\n You die!")
```

Comment: Could you post the error?

Comment: I think Chih Sean Hsu found your issue, but I see at least one more issue that will result in unexpected functionality: `==` is higher precedence than `or`, meaning your statements like `anwser.lower() == "1" or "open the folder"` are actually evaluated as `(anwser.lower() == "1") or "open the folder"`, and since the string "open the folder" is always `True`, this conditional statement will always be true. You would need to use `anwser.lower() == "1" or anwser.lower() == "open the folder"` or `anwser.lower() in ("1", "open the folder")` to get the functionality you want.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move `intro()` to the end of this script, and your first line `name = bot` is very wired, I assume bot is a string and the code will look like below. The code will run well.

Remember that python is script language, it will run by order of your code, so in your scenario, you run `intro()` before the definition of `computer()`, and it will pop out not define error.

```
name = 'bot'
def intro():
    print("On day you wake up but you don't remember anything, except your name.\n"
          "You are in a unknown room. Right in front of you is a unlocked Computer.\n"

          "\nWhat do you do?\n"

          "\n1) Go to the computer.\n"
          "2) Try to escape.\n"
          "3) ")

    anwser = input(">>> ")

    if anwser.lower() == "1" or "go to the computer":
        return computer()
    elif anwser.lower() == "2" or "try to escape":
        return escape()




def computer():
    print("You go to the computer and there is a folder called" +name)
    print("\nWhat do you do:\n"
          ""
          "\n1) Open the folder.\n"
          "2) Delete the folder\n"
          "3) Lock the computer and try to escape.")
    anwser = input(">>> ")

    if anwser.lower() == "1" or "open the folder":
        print("You open the folder an there a lot of dokuments.\n But you see a folder called \" Project Raspbrain \"")
    elif anwser.lower() == "2" or "delete the folder":
        print("You decide to delete the folder but you feel wired and fall on the ground.\n"
              "You die!")
    elif anwser.lower() == "3" or "lock the computer and try to escape":
        escape()

def escape():
    print("You see a door on your right side, you decide to go through it but there are two guards in front of you\n"
          "What do you do?\n"
          "\n1) Kill the guards"
          "\n 2) Run")
    anwser = input(">>>")

    if anwser == "Kill the guards" or "1":
        print("You try to kill the guards but don't have any weapons.\n Instead they kill you.\n You die")
    elif anwser == "2" or "run":
        print("You try to run but you stumble an fall on your head.\n You die!")


intro()
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Please clarify what is "bot"?. Is it a pre-defined variable or just a syntax error?

For the function error just move the intro function call to the bottom

```
def intro():
    (…)

def computer():
    (…)

def escape():
    (…)

intro()
```

Comment: Bot is a string a forgot the ""